# Javascript global variable not updating

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to access the dataCount variable from another file after its been updated by **updateData** function which takes an array as a parameter and as the pop function returns the new length I have passed that directly to the **updateStatus** function.
But even after updating it and accessing it stills gives me **0**.

// status.js file

```
var dataCount = 0;
let data = []

function updateStatus(num, opp){
    if (opp == "add"){
        dataCount += num
    } else if (opp == "sub") {
        dataCount -= num
    } else {
        dataCount = num;
    }
}

function updateData(arr){
    updateStatus(data.push(arr), 'update');
}

module.exports = {
    dataCount: dataCount,
    updateStatus: updateStatus,
    data: data,
    updateData: updateData
}
```

// middleware.js file

```
const status = require('./status');
const methods = require('./helperFunctions')

class Middleware{
    constructor(){
    }

    async populateIfLess(req, res, next){
        if (status.dataCount < 4){
            try {
                // Fetches the data from database and stores in data
                const data = await methods.fetchMeaning();
                Object.entries(data).map(entry => {
                    status.updateData([entry[0], entry[1]])
                })
                methods.log('Data populated on')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(status.dataCount)
                }, 1500);
                next()
            } catch (error) {
                methods.log(error);
                res.send({ERROR: "Something went wrong, please check log file."}).end()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share *all* the code. I don't see how you are using your said functions.

Comment: You are passing in the value into the object, not a pointer.

Comment: Then how should I do it @CharlieFish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the value of `dataCount` (which is a number so is a primitive) to a property of an object, then you are exporting the object.

Later you update the value of `dataCount` which has no effect on the object because numbers are primitive (and not handled by reference).

You need to modify `module.exports.dataCount` instead.

Comment: How should I modify it ?

Comment: You type `module.exports.dataCount` instead of `dataCount`

Comment: Okay, I got it know. Thank you for your help. Can you tell me which concept I am missing so that I can avoid making same mistake again.

Comment: I spent the first two paragraphs of this answer doing that.

Comment: Yes, I got that Thanks again.